# Asterisk record outgoing calls

Tags: asterisk

i am trying to recotd outgoing calls on asterisk and I always get empty audio file.

Can understand why :(
Part of [outgoing] to test calls

```
exten => 8916XXXXXXX,1,NoOp()
exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Verbose("Writing call")
exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Gosub(record_out,s,1(${EXTEN}))
exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/sip-trunk/${EXTEN},,T)
exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Hangup()
```

Sub to record files:

```
[record_out]
exten => s,1,Set(MCALLER=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => s,n,Set(MCALLED=${MACRO_EXTEN})
exten => s,n,Set(MDIRECTION=${IF($["${ARG1}" = ""]?IN:${ARG1})})
exten => s,n,Verbose(Call from ${MCALLER} to ${MCALLED} direction ${MDIRECTION})
exten => s,n,Set(FOLDER=/mnt/data/${MCALLER})
exten => s,n,Set(CALLFILENAME=OUT_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%C%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)}_CID_${MCALLER}_CAID_${MCALLED}_ID${UNIQUEID}_${MDIRECTION})
exten => s,n,MixMonitor(${FOLDER}/${CALLFILENAME}.wav,b)
;exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/mtt-ariel/${EXTEN},,T)
exten => s,n,Return()
```

Comment: what asterisk version? Have you tried to use "WAV" extension instead of "wav"? Is audio file zero bytes? or does it increases in size? I'm trying to break the problem into either asterisk or operating system. Try to record at /tmp and see if it works. If it works than there is a folder permission problem. If not, than something is wrong with asterisk or codecs. I will wait your reply so I can help you better.

Comment: Hello! Thnak you for your reply!
Asterisk version: 13.3.2, No, i haven't tried to use "WAV" instead of "wav" extension. Audio file 44 bytes long and it doesnt increse in size. It can record with Monitor app, so it's not permission problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ulaw instead of wav & recode it later, also passing caller-id as an argument may not work reliably, so I usually pass it as a dial-plan extension instead. Try this to see if it works (may require to install `sox`):

```
 exten => 8916XXXXXXX,1,NoOp()
 exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Verbose("Writing call")
 exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Gosub(record_out,${EXTEN},1)
 exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Dial(SIP/sip-trunk/${EXTEN},,T)
 exten => 8916XXXXXXX,n,Hangup()

 [record_out]
 exten => s,1,StopMixMonitor()
 exten => s,2,System(sox -q --single-threaded -t ul -r 8000 -c 1 ${CALLFILENAME}.ulaw ${CALLFILENAME}.wav && rm ${CALLFILENAME}.ulaw)

 exten => _X.,1,Set(MCALLER=${CALLERID(num)})
 exten => _X.,n,Set(MCALLED=${MACRO_EXTEN})
 exten => _X.,n,Set(MDIRECTION=${IF($["${EXTEN}" = ""]?IN:${EXTEN})})
 exten => _X.,n,Set(AUDIOHOOK_INHERIT(MixMonitor)=yes)
 exten => _X.,n,Verbose(Call from ${MCALLER} to ${MCALLED} direction ${MDIRECTION})
 exten => _X.,n,Set(FOLDER=/mnt/data/${MCALLER})
 exten => _X.,n,Set(CALLFILENAME=OUT_${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%C%y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)}_CID_${MCALLER}_CAID_${MCALLED}_ID${UNIQUEID}_${MDIRECTION})
 exten => _X.,n,MixMonitor(${FOLDER}/${CALLFILENAME}.ulaw,a)
 exten => _X.,n,Return()
```